# contains method of String is not working properly

Tags: java, string

I have one question but I am not able to solve this .

```
  public static  void main(String [] arg) {    
         String description = "This time only $FB is highest priority";
         List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         list.add("$FB");
         list.add("$F");
         for(String s : list) {
           if(description.contains(s)) {
              System.out.println(s);
           } 
         }
}
```

The out put I am getting is $FB and $F but this dummy string contains only one string of the list .. Is any other method to do which will give only exact match ?

Comment: Well, `$FB` does contain `$F`?

Comment: What makes you think $F is not contained in that string?

Comment: Any string that contains '$FB' will also contain '$F'.

Comment: Both of those strings are an exact match.

Comment: You could either use regexes or look for " " + s + " " to find only the complete word.

Comment: In the future, it's best to not assert that a basic String method "isn't working properly" in the title of your post. If you have a problem, always assume that it's _you_ who's doing something wrong, not the language, as that's almost always the case, and phrase your question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't blame Java. In 99% of the cases the problem is with the code.

Comment: OP clearly wants to only match tokens not substrings

Comment: First rule of programming: [It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you want to see if a *word* is contained. You can do this:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(description.split(" ")));

...
words.contains(s)
...
```

Comment: Not bad, but a regex would be more efficient.

Comment: @MightyPork No it wouldn't, specially when you're doing multiple queries.

Comment: You are creating a List and a HashSet just to call one it's method and discard it. It just doesn't feel right. You can use matcher then, that can be re-used.

Comment: @MightyPork The overhead of creating `words` is almost *nothing* (note that `asList` is O(1)). And it's worth it since it allows for constant time `contains`.

Comment: For a *single use*, the most efficient would be to iterate over description.split() and just look for the string with equals(), but arshajii's solution is very good for many queries into the same description (like the OP with a list of search terms).

Comment: sorry for posting such a bad words

Answer (score 8):

You can use a regular expression to check if a string contains a word:

```
if (description.matches(".*\\b"+Pattern.quote(s)+"\\b.*")) {
    ...
}
```

The anchors `\b` match a word boundary.

Comment: You can't do that if a part of the expression depends on the loop variable. You could create a regular expression that uses alternation to match all options, though.

Answer (score 0):

`contains` is a well-documented and a (hopefully) well-tested method of an enterprise-level software framework, which (as a rule of thumb) *usually* means it is working properly.

In this particular case, the `contains` method is working fine. Your initial string contains `$FB`, so it also contains `$F` (and `FB` and `$` and `F` and `B`, if you think about it).

Maybe (and I'm making a wild guess) instead you're trying to find what's contained after the last found item. In that case, don't use `contains`, use `indexOf`, save the value and then search from that saved value and on.

**Edit** per request, here is a sample of such code. Note that I haven't tested it, so there may be some checks missing:

```
     int currentIndex = 0;
     for(String s : list) {
       int foundIndex = description.indexOf(s, currentIndex);
       if(foundIndex >= 0) {
          System.out.println(s);
          currentIndex = foundIndex + 1;
       } 
     }
```

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain the rationale?

Comment: Can you please post one sample code

Comment: @PuneetSrivastava If what I described in the third paragraph is what you actually were looking for, please see my edit for an example code snippet.

Comment: @ Theodoros Chatzigiannakis it is not working as expected It is giving $F not $FB

Comment: @PuneetSrivastava Have you put in `list` `$FB` first?

Comment: No $F is the first Element of List i.e. a sorted list

Comment: @PuneetSrivastava In that case, it's normal that it finds `$F` first, since that's what you're asking it to find first. Then it moves on, without repeating the find. It's a little unclear what you meant initially in your question, but if you want to find *word matches*, take a look at the answers of the other people, as they may be what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution, maybe not be the best or more efficient, but works, and shows the power of this libraries.
So, you can use lambdaj ([download here](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/files/lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar) - [website](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)) and hamcrest ([download here](http://hamcrest.googlecode.com/files/hamcrest-1.3.zip) - [website](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)), this libraries are very powerfull for managing collections, the following code is very simple and works perfectly:

```
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.having;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.on;
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.select;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.stringContainsInOrder;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class StringContains_03{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> source =  Arrays.asList("This time only $FB,$RUG is highest priority".split(" "));
            List<String> patterns = Arrays.asList("$FB","$F");

            boolean patternsExistsInSource = select(source, having(on(String.class), stringContainsInOrder(patterns))).size()>0;
            System.out.println(patternsExistsInSource);//shows: true
            System.out.println(select(source, having(on(String.class), stringContainsInOrder(patterns))));//shows the matches: [$FB,$RUG]
    }
}
```

Note that only with this line you know if the pattern is in another.

```
 boolean patternsExistsInSource = select(source, having(on(String.class), stringContainsInOrder(patterns))).size()>0;
```

With this libraries you can solve your problem in one line. You must add to your project: **hamcrest-all-1.3.jar** and **lambdaj-2.4.jar**.

**NOTE**: This will help you assuming you can have alternatives to your code. I hope this will be useful.

**(EDITED)** Now works too for the case, ***"This time only $FB,$RUG is highest priority"***.

Comment: This will not work when String description like "This time only $FB,$RUG is highest priority"

Comment: @PuneetSrivastava thanks for the example, the code was corrected, now it works.